# css-opacity issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index, opacity

I have a jQuery cycle script (which I wrote, so it's not high quality) that basically cycles `<li>` elements by animating their opacity.  For example, say I have three `<li>` elements. The script would set the opacity of all elements but the first one to 0, then when a "next" button is clicked, it will animate the opacity of the first one to 0, then animate the opacity of the second one to 1, and so forth.  At the same time, I have a `setInterval` running that literally **clicks** the "next" button every four seconds.

The problem is, if the user clicks the "next" button at the same time as the `setInterval` pushes it, the opacity of the elements messes up, and some elements end up on top of each other.

Could anyone suggest a solution?  Would it work better if I used the `.hide()` function instead of the `.css('opacity')`?

**EDIT**: This is the code

```
$('ul#news > li').css({opacity:0.0}).filter('ul#news  li.firstNews').css({opacity:1.0});
$('#newsLeft').click(function() {

    var $active = $('ul#news li.active');
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('ul#news li.firstNews');

        $active.animate({opacity:0.0}, 300, function() {
            //when done animating out, animate next in
            $next.css({opacity:0.0})
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 400, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
        });
    });

    return false; 
}); //clickRight
```

Comment: can you upload your code or jsfiddle?

Comment: So why aren't you using one of the bajillion pre-existing, high-quality jQuery scripts that does the same thing?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: You're right, poor decision on my part.  I was stubborn and wanted to try to code one myself about 1.5 years ago.  I have since grown and don't waste my time writing a simple cycle script when there are so many high-quality ones publicly avilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the animation timer when the next-button is hovered. Example below.

```
var animTimerDelay = 4000,
    animTimerID = null;

function animTick() {
    // Animation code here

    resetTimer();
}

function resetTimer() {
    if (animTimerID !== null) {
        clearTimeout(animTimerID);
    }

    animTimerID = setTimeout(animTick, animTimerDelay);
}
```

Comment: This is also an excellent idea. In fact, this is probably what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

prevent mouse event during animation. 
every time I use this method. 
like,

```
$('#newsLeft').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('blockEvent')) return false; // return if it's locked
    $(this).addClass('blockEvent');        // lock it with 'blockevent' class         

    var $active = $('ul#news li.active');
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('ul#news li.firstNews');

    $active.animate({opacity:0.0}, 300, function() {
        //when done animating out, animate next in
        $next.css({opacity:0.0})
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 400, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.addClass('active');
                $('#newsLeft').removeClass('blockEvent'); // unlock after all animations
        });
    });

    return false; 
}); //clickRight
```

good luck :)